# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error -- in dotnet installation using tar.gz

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-3.1

I tried to install dotnet 3.1.22 in ubuntu machine using "dotnet-sdk-3.1.416-linux-arm64.tar.gz" file and pointed to same path DOTNET_ROOT and PATH

```
export DOTNET_ROOT=/home/ubuntu/dotnet-sdk/
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/dotnet-sdk:$PATH
```

getting error like while trying to get the info "dotnet --info"

> -bash: /home/ubuntu/dotnet-sdk/dotnet: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

[image]

How to resolve this issue? How to install dotnet 3.1.22 version in ubuntu machine

Comment: You are downloading ARM64 version. Is this correct?